# Variables range in JS functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to use const array for append function, but i seems it can't be seen there.

I tried to add arguments to function nextAppend, but it has no use.

```
function displayCombat()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "../php/players_fight.php",
        cache: false,

        success: function (json) {

            const battleLog = JSON.parse(json);

            for (i = 1; i < battleLog.length; i++)
            {
                $('#cWin').append('').delay(200).queue(function nextAppend()
                {
                    $(this).append(battleLog[i]);
                    nextAppend();
                });
            }
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

In result nothing is appearing on log div.
"Duplicated" solution does not work...

Comment: Array indexes start at `0`, not `1`.

Comment: can you plz provide an html that uses that js?

Comment: 0 index is empty

Comment: <div class = "col-md-12  col-lg-6 combatWindow" id = "cWin">
   
   <script> displayCombat(); </script>

  </div>